# Image segmentation in presence of noisy background

Tags: image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

Attached is the image in which the bright white contour near the green one is the contour of interest. The green one is an approximate automatic initialization. The gradient is almost non existent in the region near the automatically initialized contour. Hence, active contours and other gradient based methods fail without moving a bit.

Along the normal of the initialized contour, I searched for maximum intensities (and also reasonably close the initialized contour). Deleted outliers and smoothed the detected curve to finally detect the smooth curve. But there are some issues with this. If anyone can suggest something different, if would be really useful.

[image]

Comment: I have a way to get this http://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQow.png ... but I a not sure if that is what you want ... ping me

Answer (score 1):

> The gradient is almost non existent in the region near the automatically initialized contour. Hence, active contours and other gradient based methods fail without moving a bit.

Use the [Gradient Vector Flow](http://ww.vavlab.ee.boun.edu.tr/courses/574/materialx/Active%20Contours/xu_GVF.pdf)* external force function on your active contours.  It uses a diffusion process to extend the influence of high-gradient pixels.  With the right parameters, it will definitely work on the shown initial curve.

*If this link ever dies, search for *Snakes, Shapes, and Gradient Vector Flow*
 by Chenyang Xu and Jerry L. Prince.

Answer (score 0):

This is already a good achievement. Finding an initial contour in this mess is 80% of the solution !

You can now try by straightening this initial contour, i.e. working in (curvilinear abscissa, distance) coordinates, so that the plot of the initial contour becomes a line segment and the true contour a quasi-straight line.

In these unwarped coordinates, after resampling, you can use a Hough transform (possibly piecewise to allow some deformation).

Anyway, there is something missing in your problem statement: what are you looking for ?